# In sikulix, how can i make a while loop with condition that it won't repeat after countdown ends?

Tags: automation, sikuli, rpa

I want to make a while loop that wont repeat after designated time. I am not a coder by the way, thanks for understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I have been asked to expand my answer so I will add comments to explain each line. Also the answer is not sikuli specific and can be used for any python/jython code.

```
# import time module
import time           

# define how many seconds loop will last
loopForSeconds = 30   

# get current time in seconds since epoch
t0 = time.time()      

# loop while time delta is less than required (30 seconds in this example)
while time.time()-t0 < loopForSeconds:    
   
   # do something in the loop    
   print "This will repeat for 30 seconds"
   
   # you may want to slow down your loop by adding some sleep time
   # in this case add 1 second to slow down the loop
   # so there will be about 30 loops for 30 seconds
   # depends on other commands in the loop
   time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: This has the potential to be a great answer. Can I suggest you expand your answer to also explain why this solution works for the question?